# JVM is crashing in a call of RUNJVA from a CL program on AS400 machine

Tags: java, jvm, ibm-midrange, jvm-crash

I am calling a runnbale jar from a CL program by using RUNJVA command two times with different parameters as follows:

```
RUNJVA     CLASS('/MYFOLDER/JAVA/project.jar') +
               PARM('INIT' '129.186.121.33' 'TESTLIB') +
               OUTPUT(* *CONTINUE)

   RUNJVA     CLASS('/MYFOLDER/JAVA/project.jar') +
               PARM('CLOSE' '129.186.121.33' 'TESTLIB') +
               OUTPUT(* *CONTINUE)
```

The first call finishes successfully; and the second call started but terminated soon without logging an exception in the log file.
**NOTE:** the code is surrounded by a try-catch(Throwable) block.

**Important point:** the JVM crash is occurring at the point where I create the DB2 connection as:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:*local;translate binary=true;prompt=false;naming=sql;libraries=TESTLIB");
```

or sometime, when creating the AS400 object as:

```
com.ibm.as400.access.AS400 server = new com.ibm.as400.access.AS400();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A stack trace and error message would be helpful here. Maybe you could modify your try-catch block to produce one?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy the try catch block(Throwable) is already been placed , but the JVM crashing not able to produce any error message in the log/System.out.

Answer (score 1):

Actually problem was coming due to RCLRSC command is used in middle of process in CL program

[Message MCH3402 from QC2IO](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1010406)

So the problem is fixed after removing the RCLSRC.